# My 2nd Monitor suddenly stopped working

Tags: laptop, monitors, hdmi

So I was trying to use my second monitor on my Ubuntu laptop for class as usual, but for some reason it wasn't picking up signal from my laptop at all. I tried to see if it was a problem with my monitor so I tried connecting my PS4 and it worked fine. I also switched hdmi cables and still nothing. I don't think I changed anything from one day to the next so I'm not sure what the problem is.

This is the xrandr output without the monitor:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And it is the exact same with the monitor plugged in. I've restarted the machine twice now, but the problem persists.

Comment: Does the problem persist after rebooting? Also, what operating system are you using? If the problem is still there after rebooting, please [edit] your question and add the output of `xrandr` first without the second monitor connected and then with the second monitor.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu

Comment: And what happens if you reboot? The xrandr output shows only one recognized monitor. You can try restarting the X server, or perhaps the udev daemon if that's what controls it, but restarting is by far the simplest. This is most likely just a transient problem that will go away and not come back if you restart.

Comment: Yeah I've restarted it twice now. And the monitor works fine on my ps4...is my hdmi port broken? It was literally fine yesterday and I haven't even moved my laptop since

Comment: Hmm. If the monitor works on another machine and restarting doesn't help, then yes, a hardware problem does seem to be a possibility. However, it's weird for it to happen suddenly like that. Let's see if anyone posts an answer...

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that I had an update with ubuntu but that's about it. i don't know if that would've changed anything.

Comment: Try booting into a live Ubuntu CD to see if that helps.

Comment: Try `udevadm monitor` to monitor device manager, plug cable and see if `udev` sees any change.